# Hitting ESC while editing tags may add duplicates

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-tag-editor

I found this by accident:

1. Click "edit tags"
2. Press Backspace
3. Press Space
4. Press Esc (repeat)

Copies of the last tag are added. This also works with the other tags.

That said, it is possible to add duplicate tags via the normal process and they are filtered out when saving, so it's not an issue per se.

Comment: [Reproduced](http://i.imgur.com/RMNlZEW.png) - I can just hit _esc_ over and over and insert the tag repeatedly.

Comment: I can't repro this in Chrome, is this related to a specific browser?

Comment: Mine is FF26 (on GNU/Linux).

Comment: No repro with Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m). Though I can add the same tag twice same as I add different tags (by typing).

Comment: yeah I can reproduce this in Firefox but not Chrome or IE. This must be Firefox specific

Comment: I'm also using FF26, so maybe it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out Firefox handles the ESC key differently from all other browsers. Fix rolling with next build, `2014.1.17.1868` on meta and `2014.1.17.1314` on sites.

Comment: Thanks, can't reproduce now. (Are these DATE thingies supposed to be replaced by anything?)

Comment: @Raphael those thingies are build version, see in the left side of the footer, right now it's `rev 2014.1.17.1869` here on Meta meaning the fix was deployed in the previous build already. The first three parts are indeed date when the build was deployed, the last part is unique build number that always increases by 1 every build. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I figured, but I thought maybe some automated replacement did not happen when, in fact, we were supposed to be the replacers (or m0sa simply waited until he knew the date). Thanks!

Comment: @Raphael oh, just noticed the first revision. That's something new, but 100% manual. (we can also replace it by our own if the dev forgets :))

Comment: @samo as a dev, why not develop new magic link [rev:1868] that will auto translate to the date that build was released? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard the build number is for sure once dev builds, the date depends on when production deploys that same code...magic links that depend on API calls to our build system isn't a great idea

Comment: @Nick fair enough, was just looking for a way to save you some time on these and prevent mistakes. (of course safest way would be to just say "fixed in next build :))